# Примечание не в прямой речи

Tags: недопустимая-метка

•   По словам политолога, инцидент с Ивановым (его задержание, досудебные обвинения и домашний арест — Ред.) показал недоверие граждан к правоохранительной системе.

В приведенном предложении из статьи автора (не в прямой речи) есть пояснение такого рода, как *его задержание, досудебные обвинения и домашний арест*, нужно ли примечание редактора оформлять так, как это делается в прямой речи. Или редактору (редакции, изданию) нужно подчеркнуть, что это примечание именно его. С другой стороны, если написать: *По словам политолога, инцидент с Ивановым (его задержание, досудебные обвинения и домашний арест) показал недоверие граждан к правоохранительной системе*, то читатель может подумать, что это сказал политолог.

Если же предложение такое: *Инцидент с Ивановым (его задержание, досудебные обвинения и домашний арест. — Ред.) показал недоверие граждан к правоохранительной системе*, то, наверное, указывать, что пояснение в скобках сделано редакцией, необязательно в любом случае. Ведь это не прямая речь, пишет автор, и уточнять, что это поясняет именно редакция, а не автор статьи, разве принципиально. Для читателя это, наверное, не важно.

Comment: Для читателя, может, и не важно, а для редакции, может, и важно. По судам ведь политолог затаскает...

Comment: Niemand! Не политолог затаскает, а сочинитель статьи! )))

Comment: А-а, да, скорее сочинитель. ))

Answer (score 4):

Верно:

*По словам политолога, инцидент с Ивановым (его задержание, досудебные обвинения и домашний арест. — **Ред.**) показал недоверие граждан к правоохранительной системе.*

Точка перед "Ред.", а также шрифтовое выделение автора пометы обязательны по правилам оформления, а скобки означают, что суть инцидента передаёт (уточняет) не автор статьи, а именно редакция.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Принципиально важно наличие указания "по словам политолога":

если их нет и весь текст принадлежит автору написанного, уточнений не нужно,

однако,

если уточнение делает не написавший статью, а редактор, то без согласования с автором такую правку вносить нельзя (то есть помета "Ред." обязательна): возможно, автор иначе передал бы смыслосоставляющую инцидента.

---

А когда пометы не нужны?

[**§ 54.5**](http://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827540.html)

> Если автор или редактор вставляет в цитату свой текст, поясняющий
>   предложение либо отдельные слова цитаты, то этот текст помещают в
>   прямых или угловых скобках; инициалы автора, а также слово *Ред.* в
>   этом случае не ставят: Н. С. Щукин вспоминал об А. П. Чехове: «Чтобы
>   стать настоящим писателем, — учил он  <А. П. Чехов>,  — надо посвятить
>   себя исключительно этому делу».